# Keep a program running after closing a console, after the program has started

Tags: unix, nohup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I detach a process from Terminal, entirely?](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely)

I've a program running in a Unix console on a remote Unix computer. I (stupidly) didn't run it using `nohup &`, and now I need to close the local console.

Is there any way to have it keep running remotely after closing the local console?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your shell is `bash`, they you can use `disown`. Ctrl-Z to suspend the process, then `disown -h` to make it not receive SIGHUP.

Comment: Brilliant solution. It worked :-)

Comment: Just curious: as the process is suspended, shouldn't this eventually be followed with `bg` or something like that? Or does `disown -h` resume it as well?

Comment: Will this work if the process is running inside `screen`? I would like to continue running the process in my regular `xterm` instead.

Comment: IIRC once disowned it won't be connected to any terminal

Answer (score 5):

On Solaris 9, you can use `nohup -p <pid>` to nohup a running process.  [Here's an interesting explanation](http://blogs.oracle.com/ahl/entry/inside_nohup_p) of the implementation.  I don't know if this has been implemented on any other Unices.

Comment: nohup: invalid option -- p
Doesn't work on gentoo, ubuntu or fedora (the unixes I tried this on), but thanks nevertheless :-) Good to know Solaris has it.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl-Z to suspend the process, then `bg` to cause the program to go into the background and keep running until it completes.

Comment: Problem is that if I close the console, also the background processes will stop.
I need something that detaches the process from the console, like nohup does, but after the process has started :-)

Comment: And I don't think 'nohup bg &' will work either :-(

Comment: I tried it on one of my systems and it kept running fine when I logged out (just used `du / >> temp` as the test progrm) but I understand being hesitant if you don't want to lose the program or it's results.

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford to stop the program and restart it before logging out, then stop it and restart it through **screen**, which is a must for anybody using remote connections to unix hosts.

Comment: I think the main problem here is precisely that he would like to not stop the program.

Comment: Yeah, I would like the program not to be stopped :-)

Comment: I would highly suggest screen for future use of such a situation (I pretty much always have a screen session running on any system i have a sehll o).

Comment: Several years later, I realized I was a fool not to be using screen :-)